# Check if string contains calculation

Tags: javascript, string, eval

The question is as simple as the title: How do I make sure a string contains a calculation.

I have a string which should contain a calculation. The string could be something like this: `"10 * 10 / 2 * 3"`. But there are always people who want to break things, so I want to check if it's a calculation. The user could fill in something like this: `"alert('hi!')"`.

When I use `eval()`, it will still alert the user (if the user filled in: `"alert()"`).

Does anyone know how I can check if the string contains a calculation and nothing else?

Comment: possibly with a regex and a white list for signs/numbers.

Comment: Could you give me an example of a regex for my case, @NinaScholz?

Comment: Please don't use `eval` with user inputted code. That could lead to troves of issues :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to check if a string contains an arithmetic operation, you coul match it with a regexp like this:

```
([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+[\/\+\-\*])+([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)
```

**BUT**, i strongly suggest to use a javascript library as [mathjs](http://mathjs.org/), or the [JavaScript Expression Evaluator library](http://silentmatt.com/javascript-expression-evaluator/), with which you can do, for example:

```
Parser.evaluate("3 ^ x", { x: 7 });
```

These libraries will take care to ignore code injection, for sure... :-)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I'd recommend a different solution.

Rather than trying to `white list` your string to ensure it is just math expressions, I'd recommend you try to use library specifically for handling math in the first place.

I have no experience with it, but a quick google of "javascript math parsers" brought me to this one:  http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html

Answer (score 0):

You could just check the input sting for characters. If the sting contains any characters like (a,b,c ... z) then you do not eval it.